# Selecting untagged text with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have the following HTML;

```
<p class="postcontent">
<img src="#">
Some Text
</p>
```

I want to be able to hide only the text.
So far I have this;

```
  jQuery(function($) {
$(".postcontent").$('[type=text]').hide();
  });
```

Edit: I don't have any control over the html so I need to add it by Jquery.

Comment: What you have so far isn't a reasonable jquery.  what does this suppose to do:`jQuery(function($)`? and you can't chain selectors this way.

Comment: @gdoron: `jQuery(function($) {...});` is a shortcut for jQuery's `.ready()` function. The `$` parameter will be a local reference to `jQuery`.

Comment: @amnotiam. `function($){...}` is more than enough.

Comment: @gdoron: Not really. That's just a function. You need to pass a function to the jQuery function for it to run when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @amnotiam. sorry. I meant `$(function(){...})`

Comment: @gdoron: Yes. The code in the question is often used with `jQuery.noConflict()`, so that globally there's only `jQuery`, but inside the handler you have the `$` reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the text on the FLY and then hide it:

#### HTML:

```
<p class='postcontent'> <a href=#> dsds </a> aaa </p>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$('.postcontent').contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType == 3; })
             .wrap('<label"> <label />').parent().hide();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/g5AN2/1)

---

**Update based on a comment:**
Why does it create two labels? that's easy because it **has two text nodes...**:

```
<p class='postcontent'> (!!FirstTextNode!!)
    <a href=#> dsds </a> (!!SecondTextNode!!) aaa 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I don't understand why it creates an empty <label> <label /> inside the <label> wrap.

Comment: _If the node is a text node, the nodeType property will return 3._ (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) For anyone like me who was initially confused about `this.nodeType == 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply CSS to a text node directly, as far as I know.

You probably need to wrap the text you want to hide in a new element like a `div` or `span`.  Try something like

```
<p class="postcontent">
<img src="#">
<span class="posttext">
Some text
</span>
</p>
```

Then

```
$(".postcontent .posttext").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap the text in another element, such as a `span` or a `label` and hide that:

**HTML**

```
<p class="postcontent">
    <img src="#">
    <label>some Text</label>
</p>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".postcontent > label").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't edit the source html, you would have to use `.contents` to get the text nodes:

```
$(".postcontent").contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType == 3){
        $(this).wrap("<div>").parent().hide();
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wg6Pw/

Answer (score 0):

This will clear the text in your example.  You could then store the text and add it back in if you needed to.  Here's a jsfiddle that breaks down how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/SXgZc/

```
var pc = $('.postcontent');
pc.html(pc.html().replace(pc.text().trim(), ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text you want to hide in an element, and then hide by calling the id.