# How to hide an untagged text node in a wordpress article?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, text, tags, nodes

I was following this article with no success ([Selecting untagged text with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072905/selecting-untagged-text-with-jquery)) turning to the boards now after seeing this possible solution:

`$('article.et_pb_post').contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType == 3; })
             .wrap('<label"> <label />').parent().hide();`

Here is my [JSFiddle attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/zks0rtdc/4/).

Basically, I'm trying to integrate the [Co-Authors Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) plugin for WordPress into my custom [Divi](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) child theme. I've been successful with just about everything else except in the Divi Blog module that's used on the homepage. The JS Fiddle link shows a very simplified version of an article with multiple authors.

I don't know where the plugin generates the "and" for multiple authors, or I would just edit the plugin. So I'm stuck with an untagged text node that I cannot hide.

My question is; how can I either hide that text node, or target it in JS/JQuery to add tags that I *can target*?

Thank you

Comment: For starters you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/61soots0/

Comment: Haha. Thank you. I'm new to using fiddle...can you tell?